# How to change printing behaviour in DrRacket for R6RS to print results like with #lang racket

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs

When I'm running a program in the IDE, version 5.3.5--2013-06-18(-/f), for `#lang racket`, eg.

```
#lang racket

(+ 4 5)
(/ 10 2)
```

When pressing <kbd>Run ></kbd>, the interaction window gets `"9\n5\n"` printed to the interactions window. The same version as `R6RS`

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base))

(+ 4 5)
(/ 10 2)
```

It seems I get no output when pressing <kbd>Run ></kbd> when language is `R6RS`. Is there anywhere I can change this behavior, in `Preferences` perhaps?

Comment: Personally, I think it's broken to rely on top-level expressions being printed. (Sure, it's understandable if you're in a REPL, but this isn't a REPL, and also, I don't think R6RS modules support being used like a REPL.) Are you sure you can't just `display` them directly?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I agree that it should not print anything when running as an application, but in a IDE one could break some rules to ease development. I'm currently using a macro (like `begin`) that uses display, but it's not optimal.